# Throw some light on this comment from Doctrine 2 module 'ObjectExists.php'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am right now working with the Doctrine 2 stuff and landed upon the Doctrine modules for validations like `ObjectExists.php` and `NoObjectExists.php`.

My question is that from the original code which can be found [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Validator/ObjectExists.php).

```
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array $options required keys are `object_repository`, which must be an instance of
     * Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository, and `fields`, with either
     * a string or an array of strings representing the fields to be matched by the validator.
     * @throws \Zend\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        if (!isset($options['object_repository']) || !$options['object_repository'] instanceof ObjectRepository) {
            if (!array_key_exists('object_repository', $options)) {
                $provided = 'nothing';
            } else {
                if (is_object($options['object_repository'])) {
                    $provided = get_class($options['object_repository']);
                } else {
                    $provided = getType($options['object_repository']);
                }
            }

            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Option "object_repository" is required and must be an instance of'
                    . ' Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository, %s given',
                $provided
            ));
        }

        $this->objectRepository = $options['object_repository'];

        if (!isset($options['fields'])) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(
                'Key `fields` must be provided and be a field or a list of fields to be used when searching for'
                    . ' existing instances'
            );
        }

        $this->fields = $options['fields'];
        $this->validateFields();

        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

I cannot get the fact that here it is mentioned *"`$options` required keys are `object_repository`, which must be an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository`"*

Since `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository` is an interface, how should I decode that statement?

Or in other words how can I call this constructor of `ObjectsExists` class and pass `object_repository`, which must be an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository`?

Can somebody throw some light on this, I'm getting into this stuff, so do not be harsh on my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository` is an interface you cannot instantiate it but you can implement it.

```
class MyObjectRepository implements Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository
{
    // ...
}
```

Now every instance of `MyObjectRepository` will met the `object_repository` requirement of `ObjectsExists`.

```
new ObjectsExists(array(
    'object_repository' => new MyObjectRepository(),
    // ...
));
```

---

More about [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

> `instanceof` is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class.
>
> `instanceof` can also be used to determine whether a variable is an instantiated object of a class that inherits from a parent class.
>
> `instanceof` can also be used to determine whether a variable is an instantiated object of a class that implements an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The most common class that implements Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository is Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.

So, if you're using Doctrine ORM, the object_repository option should be something like your UserRepository (either explicitly defined, or just the generic one you get back from `$em->getRepository('User')`)

The reason it's not explicitly defined is because [No]ObjectExists validators aren't in the DoctrineORMModule, but just the DoctrineModule.  So if you're *not* using ORM, you just need to create your own UserRepository class that implements ObjectRepository.